# Sharp sudden pain in torso?

Tags: pain, posture, stretching

I've got this sharp sudden pain from my belly button towards my genitals. It feels like there is a string hooked onto my belly button and being pulled. This happens when I would sit up straight or extend my torso and will only occur every few months. What is the cause of this and is it something I have to worry about?

Comment: Go see a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Check with doctor first.

1 - i think you have spin or disk hernia near L5-S1 or so

2 - is your posture poor or stable?

3 - if you sneeze (simulate real sneeze) does the pain triggers?

Drink lot of water if the pain is like you explained from belly to pelvic muscle

Comment: My posture is stable and it doesn't pain when I sneeze in any way. You mentioned that drinking a lot of water... What is more in the lines of what I'm experiencing is from the belly to the pelvic. Could it perhaps be that if I'm bloated or have eaten a lot that it puts tension on the muscles by pushing them in an unnatural manner?